# How to set growl life programmatically in JSF (Primefaces)?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Is it possible to set the growl life duration programmatically in my Bean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either

1. Bind the client-side growl component to a server-side instance of the same component

   ```
   Growl growl = new Growl(); //Growl is from org.primefaces.component.growl.
   growl.setLife(6000);
   //getter & setter
   ```

   and in your view:

   ```
   <p:growl binding="#{myBean.growl}" autoUpdate="true" globalOnly="true" id="theGrowl" widgetVar="aGrowl"/>
   ```
2. Or use the following javascript call (by way of the `RequestContext` if you prefer)

   ```
      aGrowl.setRemovalTimeout(600);
   ```

   Where `aGrowl` is the `widgetVar` value you would've configured on your `<p:growl/>` component in your JSF view

Comment: the second tip seems not to be correct: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/growl/growl.js

Comment: This answer is for a 5-year old version of primefaces @wutzebaer

Answer (score 0):

The Growl class provides a setter for the `life` property: [Growl#setLife(int)](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/component/growl/Growl.html#setLife%28int%29)

Comment: Thanks for answer. How can i implement it in my Bean. Tried this, but doesn't work.                 RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("form:messages.setLife(5)");